# Animated movie that aired on Cartoon Network about a world of toys

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

This has been bugging me for a LONG time now and was hoping someone knew the title to this animated movie I saw a long time ago on Cartoon Network. When I say long, it possibly aired on Cartoon Network in the UK over 5 years ago. It was a animated movie with a very cartoon-like style and I haven't heard of it since.

As for the plot, it revolved around this other dimension to earth called Toy land or something, which as you might guess, involves a world solely inhabited by toys and their 'human' princess. Due to the threat of an army of evil toys, the princess heads to the human world to find their 'saviour' or something. I believe the idea was no one could see her, however she did have this special rock or crystal. The rule was the first human to touch it would get transported to Toy land and become prince/king. During a football game at a random school she drops the rock/gem near a boy she likes who completely ignores it, however another random boy finds it and picks it up, transporting him to the toy world.

From then on my memory becomes more hazy. I do remember certain bits such as how the princess immediately starts hating the boy (despite the fact that the citizens of Toy land seem to like him), although in the end she does fall for him. When in Toy land I remember him having some sort of toy robot suit and sword for fighting off the villains, and I do remember the movie having a sequel. Only thing else I remember is the fact that every time the boy transports himself off to Toy land, he leaves behind a doll of himself which his Uncle/Dad who owns a toy shop looks after due to mistaking it for part of his stock. I also remember that in one of the sequels (there might of been 2 sequels), one of the evil toys makes it to the human realm and starts twisting/attacking the doll of the main character which reveals the fact that if the doll is injured, the main character will be hurt too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like *[The Toy Warrior](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0363141/)*, released in 2005.

> The Land Of Toys is a world of pure imagination, ruled by the popular doll Princess Sherbet, but when the mysterious Dark One threatens Sherbet's toy kingdom, she turns to the real world in search of a heroic Warrior Prince... Unfortunately, she ends up with the imaginative trouble-maker Jinoo. When Jinoo accidentally touches Sherbet's magical Warrior Stone, the spunky sixth-grader is suddenly transported to the Land Of Toys to become the powerful Toy Warrior! Aided by the reluctant Princess Sherbet, the transforming Police-bot, R.J., and Jinoo's amazingly loyal backpack, Ping, Jinoo is ready to play Toy Warrior and chase the dark forces across the landscape of imagination. The evil is spreading and now both the real world and the very Well of Imagination itself are at stake! Our only hope is a hero with heart... the Toy Warrior Jinoo!